# Azure Machine Learning Studio analog

Tags: machine-learning

Azure offers GUI for designing models called Machine Learning Studio. Are there any open source alternatives?

Answer (score 1):

R Commander lets you click on buttons.

Comment: RStudio is IDE, not a visual designer tool.

Answer (score 1):

[WEKA](https://www.cs.waikato.ac.nz/ml/weka/), from University of Waikato, is GUI-based, open-source software.

[image]